# Explicit factor NAs in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame with ages binned in ranges of 5 years and the frequency of a condition happening in males/females. The problem is that there were no occurrences in either gender for example in the range 15-20.

```
structure(list(age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), .Label = c("[0,5]", 
"(5,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", "(20,25]", "(25,30]", "(30,35]", 
"(35,40]", "(40,45]", "(45,50]", "(50,55]", "(55,60]", "(60,65]", 
"(65,70]", "(70,75]", "(75,80]", "(80,85]", "(85,90]", "(90,95]", 
"(95,100]"), class = "factor"), male = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 
9L, 20L, 33L, 49L, 104L, 112L, 176L, 159L, 140L, 94L, 72L, 32L, 
6L, 2L), female = c(1L, 1L, NA, 7L, 7L, 4L, 23L, 39L, 44L, 74L, 
94L, 111L, 124L, 129L, 110L, 92L, 76L, 30L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), groups = structure(list(age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L), .Label = c("[0,5]", "(5,10]", "(10,15]", "(15,20]", 
"(20,25]", "(25,30]", "(30,35]", "(35,40]", "(40,45]", "(45,50]", 
"(50,55]", "(55,60]", "(60,65]", "(65,70]", "(70,75]", "(75,80]", 
"(80,85]", "(85,90]", "(90,95]", "(95,100]"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), ptype = integer(0), class =    c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If I check the levels it properly shows all levels.
what I would want is a data frame where all ranges of ages show up and when they don't exist substitute then by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  ungroup %>%
  complete(age, fill = list(male = 0, female = 0))

#   age       male female
#   <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 [0,5]        2      1
# 2 (5,10]       1      1
# 3 (10,15]      1      0
# 4 (15,20]      0      0
# 5 (20,25]      4      7
# 6 (25,30]      8      7
# 7 (30,35]      9      4
# 8 (35,40]     20     23
# 9 (40,45]     33     39
#10 (45,50]     49     44
#11 (50,55]    104     74
#12 (55,60]    112     94
#13 (60,65]    176    111
#14 (65,70]    159    124
#15 (70,75]    140    129
#16 (75,80]     94    110
#17 (80,85]     72     92
#18 (85,90]     32     76
#19 (90,95]      6     30
#20 (95,100]     2      7
```